# HERE SDK TrafficUpdater.request(Geocordinate, TrafficUpdater.Listener) not returning traffic results

Tags: here-api

I have been working on integrating several HERE features into an app I am working on. Right now I am trying to add traffic data to the application. The default auto-updates aren't quite frequent enough for me (~1 min), so I am trying to use the TrafficUpdater.request(GeoCoordinate, TrafficUpdater.Listener) to manually retrieve traffic information every 5 seconds or so. The problem is, although the request line executes, the listener is never called, and I never receive any traffic updates. Below is my activity:

```
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.here.android.mpa.common.GeoCoordinate;
import com.here.android.mpa.common.GeoPosition;
import com.here.android.mpa.common.MapSettings;
import com.here.android.mpa.common.OnEngineInitListener;
import com.here.android.mpa.common.PositioningManager;
import com.here.android.mpa.guidance.TrafficUpdater;
import com.here.android.mpa.mapping.Map;
import com.here.android.mpa.mapping.MapFragment;
import com.here.android.mpa.mapping.MapTrafficLayer;
import com.here.android.mpa.mapping.MapView;
import com.here.android.mpa.mapping.TrafficEvent;

import java.io.File;
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Map map;
    private MapFragment mapFragment;
    private TrafficUpdater trafficUpdater;

    private PositioningManager.OnPositionChangedListener onPositionChangedListener = new PositioningManager.OnPositionChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPositionUpdated(PositioningManager.LocationMethod locationMethod, GeoPosition geoPosition, boolean b) {
            onLocationUpdate(geoPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPositionFixChanged(PositioningManager.LocationMethod locationMethod, PositioningManager.LocationStatus locationStatus) {

        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MapSettings.setIsolatedDiskCacheRootPath(
                getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(null) + File.separator + ".here-maps",
                "MAP_SERVICE");
        mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.init(new OnEngineInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onEngineInitializationCompleted(Error error) {
                if (error == Error.NONE) {
                    map = mapFragment.getMap();
                    initTracker();
                }
            }
        });

    }
        private void initTracker() {
        trafficUpdater = TrafficUpdater.getInstance();
        trafficUpdater.enableUpdate(false);
        PositioningManager positioningManager = PositioningManager.getInstance();
        positioningManager.addListener(new WeakReference<PositioningManager.OnPositionChangedListener>(onPositionChangedListener));
        mapFragment.getPositionIndicator().setVisible(true);
        positioningManager.start(PositioningManager.LocationMethod.GPS_NETWORK);

    }

    private boolean isTimerRunning = false;
    CountDownTimer trafficTimer = new CountDownTimer(5000,5000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            isTimerRunning = false;
            getTrafficInfo();
        }
    };

    private GeoPosition lastGeoPosition;

    private void onLocationUpdate(GeoPosition geoPosition) {
        map.setCenter(geoPosition.getCoordinate(), Map.Animation.NONE);
        Log.i("____MAINACTIVITY", "location update");
        lastGeoPosition = geoPosition;
        if(!isTimerRunning) {
            trafficTimer.cancel();
            trafficTimer.start();
            isTimerRunning = true;
        }

    }

    private TrafficUpdater.Listener trafficListener = new TrafficUpdater.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(TrafficUpdater.RequestState requestState) {
            Log.i("____MAINACTIVITY", requestState.name());
        }
    };

    private void getTrafficInfo() {
        if(lastGeoPosition != null) {
            TrafficUpdater.RequestInfo requestInfo = trafficUpdater.request(lastGeoPosition.getCoordinate(), trafficListener);
            Log.i("___MAINACTIVITY", requestInfo.getError().name());
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried several things to remedy this issue. First, I have checked all of my app permissions and project dashboard on the developer portal to ensure everything is setup properly, and it is. I was providing the listener as an anonymous method in the line we execute the request, and that did not work. I moved the listener to be a private member variable of the activity, and provided it that way, but it still isn't working. I've checked the RequestInfo returned by the method, and it always indicates an error code of NONE, so it seems as though no errors are occurring. Lastly, I set my updater frequency to once every 1.5 seconds (well above the default value), and I still receive nothing. Does anyone know a solution to this problem? I feel as though it's something simple that I'm missing. Updates from the Positioning Manager are coming through just fine, and the app is talking to our server with no problems, so I don't think it's a connectivity issue.

Answer (score 0):

The traffic feed does provide updates only in a one minute time frame. To force the application to request this in a higher frequency won't provide fresher data. I would recommend to keep the default auto-updates.